# Add markeredges in seaborn lmplot?

Tags: python, seaborn, marker

`sns.lmplot(x="size", y="tip", data=tips)`

gives a scatter plot. By default the markers have no edges.

How can I add markeredges? Sometimes I prefer to use edges transparent facecolor. Especially with dense data. However,

Neither `markeredgewidth` nor `mew` nor `linewidths` are accepted as keywords.

Does anyone know how to add edges to the markers?

Comment: You can add the markeredges with the keyword `scatter_kws`.
  
  
For example `s scatter_kws={'linewidths':1,'edgecolor':'k'}`

Answer (score 2):

As per the comment from @Sören, you can add the markeredges with the keyword scatter_kws. For example `scatter_kws={'linewidths':1,'edgecolor':'k'}`